# Set control to absolute location independent of window resize

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, location, controls

I'm new to Cocoa framework and coding for Mac OS X (using swift) and I can't figure out how to set a control (created at run-time) to use absolute location within the view. This code for example will create and add a TextField to the view:

```
var label: NSTextField?
label = NSTextField()
label?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label?.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 17)
label?.bordered = false
label?.drawsBackground = false
label?.cell?.title = "I'm a Label"
label?.cell?.editable = false
view.addSubview(label!)
```

The resulting TextField is created at location relative to the bottom-left corner of the window and I believe Y axis is flipped (somehow) such that the view origin (0,0) is on bottom-left. Moreover, if I resized the window the control move with it so it's location is always relative to that view origin. How to programmatically change the location of the control to absolute?

I tried to add a control using the designer and see if it behaves the same but it did not. The control added on design-time had an absolute location and it did not change on window resize.

Comment: So you want it absolute to the entire screen, not absolute to the window?

Comment: No I want absolute to the window only so it does not change location on window resize. Hint: disabling anchor.